# Lexical error css

Tags: css

For some reason my http://www.mobileitnext.nl/css/style.css gives Lexical errors.

This is the original code, do you guys have any idea why..? Thanks!

```
/* reset css */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

h3 .email {
    clear:both;
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;
}
body {
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0 ;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; background:#fff;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
    src: url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfontb5K2fJwj') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
}
    font-style: normal;
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: "" "";
}
a{text-decoration:none;}

/*---------------------------reset code----------------------------*/
body    { background:url(../Images/bgall.jpg);}
.clear  { clear:both; line-height:1px; font-size:1px;}
/*---------------------------Main Body Start ----------------------------*/


/*---------------------------Main Body Start ----------------------------*/

#wrapper                    {width:100%; margin:0 auto; background:url(../Images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;}
#innerWrapper               {width:765px; margin:0 auto; padding:0 0 45px 0;  }
/*---------------------------Main Body End-------------------------------*/


/*---------------------------Header Start ----------------------------*/
.header_wrapper         { width:765px; height:90px; margin:0 auto; padding:0 0 51px 0;}

.logo { width:232px; height:42px; margin:0; padding:25px 0 0 0; float:left;}
.contact_us { width:240px; height:16px; margin:0; padding:34px 0 0; float:right;}
/*---------------------------Header End ----------------------------*/


/*---------------------------Menu ----------------------------*/

.contact_form { width:765px; margin:0; padding:0 0 15px 0;} 
.Banner_wrapper { width:765px; margin:0; padding:0 0 15px 0;} 
.middlecurve { background:url(../Images/banner_middlecurve.jpg) no-repeat right 0; width:765px; height:auto; padding:15px 0 0 0 }
.bottomcurve{ background:url(../Images/bottomcurve.jpg) no-repeat right 0; width:765px; height:9px; margin:0; padding:0; }

.full_video {
    padding:0px 15px 4px 15px;
    float:left;
}
.lftbanner { float:left; width:326px; min-height:239px; margin:0; padding:30px 0 0 25px; float:left;}
.lftbanner p { font:normal 16px/24px "Helvetica", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#494949; padding:0 0 20px 0;}
h1 { font:normal 28px   'ChunkFiveRegular', serif; color:#494949; padding:0 0 10px 0; }
.searchDiv { width:309px; height:47px; margin:0; padding:0;}
.searchDiv .inputbg { background:url(../Images/searchbg.jpg) no-repeat; width:0px; height:39px; margin: 0 5px 0; padding:0 10px 0 10px; font: italic 14px/35px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#494949; text-align:center; border:0; float:left;}
.searchDiv .submit { background:url(../Images/contact.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:55px; margin:0; padding:0; font: bold 14px "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:center; border:0; float:right;}
.searchDiv .submit:hover  { background:url(../Images/contact1.png) no-repeat; width:200px; height:55px; margin:0; padding:0; font: bold 14px "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; text-align:center; border:0; float:right;}

.banner_rht { width:359px; height:273px; margin:0; padding:0 14px 0 0; float:right;}
.banner_thum{ width:359px; height:129px; margin:0; padding:0 0 14px 0;}
.banner_thum2{ width:359px; height:129px; margin:0; padding: 0 0 14px 0;}
.thumb1{ width:172px; height:129px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0 14px 0 0;}
.thumb2{ width:173px; height:129px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0;}
/*---------------------------Menu End ----------------------------*/



/*---------------------------Container  ----------------------------*/
.container_wrapper      { width:765px; height:auto; margin:0 auto; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.main_cont { width:765px; margin:0; padding:0;}


.cont_lft_div { width:365px; margin:0; padding:0px; float:left;}

.con_box1 { width:365px; height:79px; margin: 0 auto; padding:0 0 20px 0;}

.lft_con_box1 { width:77px; height:79px; margin:0; padding:0; float:left;}
.img{ width:44px; height:56px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0 0 0}
.img2{ width:53px; height:56px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0 0 0}
.img3{ width:52px; height:67px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0 0 0}
.img4{ width:58px; height:43px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px 0 0 0}

.rht_con_box1 { width:287px; height:79px; margin:0; padding:0; float:left;}
.rht_con_box1 p {font:normal 12px/18px "Helvetica", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#2e2e2e; padding:0 0 10px 0;}

h2{ font:normal 16px,  'ChunkFiveRegular'; color:#3e3e3e; padding:0 0 10px 0;}
h2 a{ font:normal 16px 'ChunkFiveRegular'; color:#3e3e3e; text-decoration:none;}

.con_box2 { width:365px; height:79px; margin: 0 auto;}

.cont_rht_div { width:365px; margin:0; padding:0px 0 0 20px; float:left;}

.bottomline { background:url(../Images/bottomline.jpg) no-repeat; width:759px; height:15px; margin:0 auto; padding:0 0 60px 0;}

h3{ font:normal 16px 'ChunkFiveRegular'; color:#4b4b4b; padding:0 0 10px 0;}


/*---------------------------Container End  ----------------------------*/

/*--------------------------- Body Styles  ----------------------------*/
#introbox {
    padding:15px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

#introbox h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
}

#introbox p {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color:#545454;
    line-height:20px;
}

#slickbox {
    padding:35px 15px 15px 15px;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

#slickbox h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
}

#slickbox p {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    color:#545454;
    line-height:20px;
}
#slick-toggle {
    margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
}

/*---------------------------Body Styles End  ----------------------------*/

/*---------------------------Footer  ----------------------------*/
.footer_wrapper { width:100%; margin:0 auto; }
.footer_Div { width:765px; margin:0 auto; height:100px;}
.footer_cell { width:745px; float:left; background: url(../Images/footerbg.jpg); padding:0 10px 10px 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom:25px !important;}

.copyright { width:383px; height:16px; margin:0; padding:20px 0 0 0; float:left;}
.copyright p { font:normal 11px "Helvetica", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#3e3e3e;}

.links{ width:100px; height:32px; margin:0; padding:10px 0 0 0; float:right;}
.links ul { list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.links ul li { list-style:none; float:left; padding:0 8px;}
/*---------------------------Footer End  ----------------------------*/
```

If you do not understand something, tell me. I will monitor this question closely.

Comment: The weird signs pop up after h3 .email { ... }

Comment: Use some online CSS validator to find the issues in your code (http://www.cssportal.com/css-validator/)

Comment: Lexical error at line 23, column 2. Encountered: "\u0a00" (2560), after : "" }਀ h3 .email {਀ऀ挀氀攀愀爀㨀戀漀琀栀㬀 font-family: sans-serif;
26   Lexical error at line 25, column 49. Encountered: "\u0a00" (2560), after : ""

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, that's why I asked this question :)

Comment: There are a bunch of chinese text included in your css.

Comment: @Arvind just delete all of the chinese text.

Comment: @Andres These chinese charachters are not in my orignal file, when I uploaded this to my server (hostgator) the symbols appeared :S

Comment: @Arvind maybe its spam? Upload a fixed version and change your password, your account was probably compromised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is special characters in your css file.Here is steps you can do

Download notepad++ from [here](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

This is advanced text editor. After downloading, open your css file with notepad++ and  Then navigate to menu `View > Show Symbols > Show all characters.`You can see special characters, and you can delete them. After deleting special chars if exists, you can save this file as utf-8.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patched version of your CSS: http://pastebin.com/dGvFcK3M

You left an unclosed rule on your CSS (line24) and also had some chinese text strewn about.

This:

http://pastebin.com/GdL4n7Yu

Note: Appears to be a story about the Qing Dinasty :)

Comment: Thanks, deleted the rule. And I have no idea how the Qing Dynasty story came there haha. So weird. My local file of the css file has no chinese characters.

Comment: @Arvind if you have access to your server logs, check if there was any access that was not you, you might have been spammed, also check if your stylesheet might be being written by your apps, that might be the case as well.

Comment: There was no unauthorized access,  I checked the log files. Maybe it written by an app.. but I think that was not the case here. It probably had to do with the file encoding, since I used a template. I did not write everything myself.

Comment: @Arvind encoding aside, the text was still there, even if you change the encoding the text will still be there, so make sure to delete it.