# Lexical error <EOF> after : ""

Tags: html, css, error-handling, lexical

I'm using this css and nothing is showing up. It was working earlier today and has now just stopped. The html is still present but when I inspect element the height is set to 0px. How do I resolve this error?

**error:** Lexical error at line 571, column 3. Encountered:  after : ""

(in this case the last } is line 571)

```
#chevron {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

#chevron:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 51%;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, 6deg);
}

#chevron:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  -o-transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
  transform: skew(0deg, -6deg);
}​
```

Comment: There is no line 571 in your code, so how could we debug this? Please include a full (but preferably minimal) example, with HTML and CSS code, that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: it helps if you let us know how is the line 571?

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with your css... there must be some missing semicolon in javascript

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, line 571 is the very last curly bracket at the end of that snippet "}"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363351/lexical-error-css

Answer (score 3):

If you copy your css from question and paste it to [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) for example, you will see strange red dot:
[image].[image]

Maybe this will help.

Comment: I see the dot, but when i delete it and copy back into my stylesheet it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the entire .css file, or only that piece?

Comment: checked the entire css and there was only the one red dot, w3 validator said thats where the error was as well but it still doesn't work